# I want to update mysql table column1 unless data exists then move to next column2

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my `MySQL` table. What I want to do is update `column1` unless data exists in `column1` then move it onto `column2` and update that one instead. The code that I currently have is constantly updating the first column.

```
UPDATE users
SET    active = 1,
       time_started = '$_POST[in_time]'
WHERE  user_id = '$_POST[user_id]
```

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: If `column1` is always populated when the row is present then you could leverage `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that mysql provides.  But think ysth's answer below is best answer.  Also, you are familiar with SQL injection and PDO?

Comment: I don't understand how this works could you explain... my current code is $sql= "UPDATE staff SET active = 1, time_started = '$_POST[in_time]' WHERE staff_id = '$_POST[staff_id]'"; what I want is if time_started is not null then update the next column which is time_in_1

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
update users set active=1, time_in_1=if(time_started is null,time_in_1,?), time_started=if(time_started is null,?,time_started) while ...
```

In effect, when time_started is null, the above does:

```
update users set time_in_1=time_in_1, time_started=?
```

(leaving time_in_1 unchanged; ? is a placeholder for your new value).
If time_started is not null, it does:

```
update users set time_in_1=?, time_started=time_started
```

(leaving time_started unchanged).  In either case, you need to provide your new value twice (assuming there is only one; maybe you want to update the second column to a different value than you would have updated the first column to?).

Comment: I don't understand how this works could you explain... my current code is $sql= "UPDATE staff SET active = 1, time_started = '$_POST[in_time]'  WHERE staff_id = '$_POST[staff_id]'";  what I want is if time_started is not null then update the next column which is time_in_1

Comment: Yes I do mean not null sorry.

Comment: It is time_started I am updating and my second column is time_in_1

Comment: The order is important; time_in_1 needs to come first.

Comment: what if I wanted to do this continuously such as after time_in_1 time_in_2 and so on

Comment: here is exactly what I want to do... I have 5 columns time_started, time_in_1, time_in_2, time_in_3, time_in_4 each one with a type of time I want to place in the current time so first place time into time_started then the next time the user uses the update button if the time has been placed into time_started already insert time into time_in_1 then im getting really confused here

Comment: certainly possible; I'll take a stab at it later.  but you know you really should have a separate table with one row for each user for each of your time_in fields, right?  what do you want to happen if all fields are already set?

Comment: if all the fields are set I want to parse an error but this should never be the case

Comment: I'll try to look at in in a couple hours, sorry